# drawImage draw the image on canvas but after any event it disappear image fabricjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

I am drawing an image on canvas via drawImage method, it draw the image but when any event is called is become blank and disappear. I tried different ways but not success. I want to show the image on canvas and not disappear, Because I convas this canvas to dataUrl which become blank.

[My working Link](http://production.technology-architects.com/doulat/curtains_new/3d_view/testCurve.php)

Please anyone who know please guide me where i am going wrong.
Below is my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Canvas.dataURL tainted(polluted) Issue</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://technology-architects.com/daulat/customizer_assets/js/bootstrap-slider.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://technology-architects.com/daulat/customizer_assets/js/jquery.liteuploader.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://files.codepedia.info/files/uploads/iScripts/html2canvas.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://technology-architects.com/daulat/customizer_assets/js/custom.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://technology-architects.com/daulat/customizer_assets/cartjs/cart.js"></script> 
<script src="https://technology-architects.com/daulat/customizer_assets/fabric-js/custom/fabricExtensions.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://technology-architects.com/daulat/customizer_assets/bgrins-spectrum/spectrum.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://technology-architects.com/daulat/customizer_assets/js/fabric.curvedText.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<style>
.canvas-container{display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;}
</style>

<canvas id="canvas" height=758 width=497 style="border:1px solid lightgrey;display:inline-block;"></canvas>

<img id="curveImg" src="http://production.technology-architects.com/doulat/curtains_new/3d_view/images/sample.png" alt="" style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;">
<button type="button" id="clickme">Click Me!</button>

<script>

  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

  var offsetY=[0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,29.5,30,30.1,30.2,30.3,30.4,30.5,30.6,30.7,30.8,30.9,30,29.5,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1,0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,29.5,30,30.1,30.2,30.3,30.4,30.5,30.6,30.7,30.8,30.9,30,29.5,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1,0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,29.5,30,30.1,30.2,30.3,30.4,30.5,30.6,30.7,30.8,30.9,30,29.5,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1,0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,29.5,30,30.1,30.2,30.3,30.4,30.5,30.6,30.7,30.8,30.9,30,29.5,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1,0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,29.5,30,30.1,30.2,30.3,30.4,30.5,30.6,30.7,30.8,30.9,30,29.5,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1,0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,29.5,30,30.1,30.2,30.3,30.4,30.5,30.6,30.7,30.8,30.9,30,29.5,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1,0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,29.5,30,30.1,30.2,30.3,30.4,30.5,30.6,30.7,30.8,30.9,30,29.5,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1,0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,29.5,30,30.1,30.2,30.3,30.4,30.5,30.6,30.7,30.8,30.9,30,29.5,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1,0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,29.5,30,30.1,30.2,30.3,30.4,30.5,30.6,30.7,30.8,30.9,30,29.5,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1,0,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,29.5,30,30.1,30.2,30.3,30.4,30.5,30.6,30.7,30.8,30.9,30,29.5,29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0.9,0.8,0.7,0.6,0.5,0.4,0.3,0.2,0.1,0]
  
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var immg = 'http://production.technology-architects.com/doulat/curtains_new/3d_view/images/sample.png';
  
      fabric.util.loadImage(immg, function(img) {
        
          for(var x=0;x<offsetY.length;x++){
            ctx.drawImage(img,
                // clip 1 pixel wide slice from the image
                x,0,1,img.height,
                // draw that slice with a y-offset
                x,offsetY[x],1,img.height
            );           
          }

 
    },null, {crossOrigin:'anonymous'}); 
 canvas.renderAll();
 
 
 
 
 $(document).on('click','#clickme',function(){
 var imagedatafinal = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
 console.log(imagedatafinal);
 $('#curveImg').attr('src',imagedatafinal);
 var imgdatafinal = imagedatafinal.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
      //ajax call to save image inside folder
      $.ajax({
     url: '../save_image.php',
     data: {
       imgdata:imgdatafinal
       },
     type: 'post',
     success: function (response) {
     $('#curveImg').attr('src',response);
     console.log(response);
     }
      });
 });
 
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/1bzkk0wL/).

You are getting this problem because you are drawing that in context and not adding that to canvas object. So after drawing in context you get that context data using `ctx.getImageData(0, 0, img.width, img.height);` After that create a canvas element and put that image data`c.getContext('2d').putImageData(data, 0, 0);` then create an fabricjs image object from that canvas image data.

*Crossorigin problem is there so fiddle not working, you can check this in your [local server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1n0e.png)

Answer (score 1):

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1bzkk0wL/3/)

You have to add image on fabric canvas as below.

```
 var imgbase64 = new fabric.Image(img, {})
 canvas.add(imgbase64);
```

And then it will work. Just make sure to check this on your local server as here it will throw CROS error.
I've changed image src to get it work as getting CORS error from your sample.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

var offsetY = [0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 29.5, 30, 30.1, 30.2, 30.3, 30.4, 30.5, 30.6, 30.7, 30.8, 30.9, 30, 29.5, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 29.5, 30, 30.1, 30.2, 30.3, 30.4, 30.5, 30.6, 30.7, 30.8, 30.9, 30, 29.5, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 29.5, 30, 30.1, 30.2, 30.3, 30.4, 30.5, 30.6, 30.7, 30.8, 30.9, 30, 29.5, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 29.5, 30, 30.1, 30.2, 30.3, 30.4, 30.5, 30.6, 30.7, 30.8, 30.9, 30, 29.5, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 29.5, 30, 30.1, 30.2, 30.3, 30.4, 30.5, 30.6, 30.7, 30.8, 30.9, 30, 29.5, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 29.5, 30, 30.1, 30.2, 30.3, 30.4, 30.5, 30.6, 30.7, 30.8, 30.9, 30, 29.5, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 29.5, 30, 30.1, 30.2, 30.3, 30.4, 30.5, 30.6, 30.7, 30.8, 30.9, 30, 29.5, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 29.5, 30, 30.1, 30.2, 30.3, 30.4, 30.5, 30.6, 30.7, 30.8, 30.9, 30, 29.5, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 29.5, 30, 30.1, 30.2, 30.3, 30.4, 30.5, 30.6, 30.7, 30.8, 30.9, 30, 29.5, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 29.5, 30, 30.1, 30.2, 30.3, 30.4, 30.5, 30.6, 30.7, 30.8, 30.9, 30, 29.5, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0]

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var immg = 'http://i.imgur.com/3tU4Vig.jpg';


var img = new Image();

img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
img.src = immg;

img.onload = function() {
  var imgbase64 = new fabric.Image(img, {
    width: 400,
    height: 500
  })
  canvas.add(imgbase64);
  canvas.deactivateAll().renderAll();

}


canvas.renderAll();




$(document).on('click', '#clickme', function() {

  var imagedatafinal = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
  console.log(imagedatafinal);
  $('#curveImg').attr('src', imagedatafinal);
  var imgdatafinal = imagedatafinal.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
  //ajax call to save image inside folder
  $.ajax({
    url: '../save_image.php',
    data: {
      imgdata: imgdatafinal
    },
    type: 'post',
    success: function(response) {
      $('#curveImg').attr('src', response);
      console.log(response);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Canvas.dataURL tainted(polluted) Issue</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://technology-architects.com/daulat/customizer_assets/js/bootstrap-slider.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://technology-architects.com/daulat/customizer_assets/js/jquery.liteuploader.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://files.codepedia.info/files/uploads/iScripts/html2canvas.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://technology-architects.com/daulat/customizer_assets/js/custom.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://technology-architects.com/daulat/customizer_assets/cartjs/cart.js"></script>
  <script src="https://technology-architects.com/daulat/customizer_assets/fabric-js/custom/fabricExtensions.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://technology-architects.com/daulat/customizer_assets/bgrins-spectrum/spectrum.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://technology-architects.com/daulat/customizer_assets/js/fabric.curvedText.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

  <style>
    .canvas-container {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
  </style>

  <canvas id="canvas" height=758 width=497 style="border:1px solid lightgrey;display:inline-block;"></canvas>

  <img id="curveImg" alt="" style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;">
  <button type="button" id="clickme">Click Me!</button>


</body>

</html>
```